# Inserting values in a Binary Tree iteratively

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree

I have a problem with inserting an Element in an Binary-Tree **iteratively**. Recursion works fine.

This is my current code:

```
class SearchTree:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.empty = True
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.empty

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

    def get_left(self):
        return self.left

    def get_right(self):
        return self.right

    def elem(self, value):
        if self.is_empty():
            return False
        elif value < self.value:
            return self.left.elem(value)
        elif value > self.value:
            return self.right.elem(value)
        else:
            return True

    def add_recursive(self, value):
        if self.is_empty():
            self.empty = False
            self.value = value
            self.left = SearchTree(value)
            self.right = SearchTree(value)
            return True
        else:
            if value < self.value:
                return self.left.add_recursive(value)
            elif value > self.value:
                return self.right.add_recursive(value)
            else:
                return False

    def add_iterative(self, value):
        new_node = SearchTree(value)
        x = self
        y = None
        while x.empty is False:
            y = x
            if value < x.value:
                x = x.left
            else:
                x = x.right
        if y is None:
            self.empty = False
            self.value = value
            self.left = SearchTree(value)
            self.right = SearchTree(value)
            return True
        elif value < y.value:
            y.left = new_node
        elif value > y.value:
            y.right = new_node
        else:
            return False

    def __str__(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            return ""
        else:
            return "(" + str(self.left) + "," + str(self.value) + "," + str(self.right) + ")"
```

And this is the testfile:

```
import random
from searchtree import SearchTree

l = []
for i in range(10):
    l.append(random.randint(0, 10))

st_re = SearchTree(10)
st_it = SearchTree(10)

for r in l:
    st_re.add_recursive(r)
    st_it.add_iterative(r)

print(l)
print(st_re)
print(st_it)
```

The current outout i'm getting:

random list: [1, 7, 6, 5, 7, 5, 10, 1, 4, 8]

binary tree added recursive:(,1,((((,4,),5,),6,),7,((,8,),10,)))

binary tree added iteratively: (,1,)

I cant find any solution to make it work, can anyone help?

Comment: why are you using same class as new node?

Comment: What does that mean exactly?

Comment: you can create a node class and store value as node

Comment: do you have an example of how i could store the value as node?

Comment: here is the link [bst](https://pastebin.com/TxdrE0ef)